# How to screen on Morningstar for GOLD rated mutual funds

Tags: investing, mutual-funds

How can I get a list of mutual funds for a given sector that are gold rated?

I am referring to mutual funds that have the MorningStar gold rating symbol that indicates MorningStar advisers are bullish on those funds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into being a premium member on Morningstar's site to get access to the fund analyst reports?

Note that this is different than looking at top rated funds as those ratings are based on past performance which may or may not continue in the future.